# Continue the process after IF statement (regardless of the condition), php

Tags: php

I have searched a lot but can't find my solution. I am new to php so I hope I can explain my question clearly.

I am trying to build a system that allows the user to update his/her information.
There are some inputs in the form which are; username, email, old-new password...

What I want to achieve is updating only the changed inputs. (blank inputs will be ignored)

So I want the username input to be checked if it is blank and keep the process working regardless of the result if username is blank or not.
By that way ı can update the table with only changed/typed inputs.

How can I achieve that?

```
if($username != "") {
    //update the username
}
// keep process going even if username condition is true.
if($email != "") {
    // update the email
}
```

PS: I didn't write the whole codes because there are at least 10 inputs and 3 selects. I tried lots of nested if,elseif,else statements so the codes I tried is so complicated and long.

I just wonder If there is a way to keep the process going after an "if statement" even if the condition is true.

**UPDATE**

I tried using just ifs, I was expecting the process will be continue but, for example;if I left blank the username and type the email, it updates the email.But if username input was typed and the email was typed; it just updates the username.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Anything you put after the `if()` statement (outside of the curly braces) *will* be processed, regardless of whether it's true.

Comment: well, that's basically how if-else blocks work. If the code doesn't continue after your if-statement, most probably an error occured

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger He does close it - the brace is just in the comment.

Comment: @Grim... Yes, just noticed.

Comment: @oGeez I tried that using just ifs, I was expecting the process will be continue but, for example;if I left blank the username and type the email, it updates the email.But if username input was typed and the email was typed; it just updates the username.

Comment: maybe you got an error, try to display the errors with [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the data is updated on a single table say `users`, then you can generate the update command on the fly using the input data and finally execute the query as

```
<?php
$qry_update = "UPDATE `users` SET " ;
if($username != ""){ 
    $qry_update .= "`username` = '$username', ";
}
if($email != ""){
 $qry_update .= "`email` = '$email', ";
}
....
....

$qry_update = rtrim($qry_update, ',');

$qry = $qry_update." where idusers = $idusers "; 

// Execute the query
?>
```

The above is conventional way of doing it. But its better to use PDO with bind params.

Comment: I tried to update the variables with mysqli,bind_param in every if statement I will tried doing it just one update like you wrote, and ı will write the result.

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP`, the code outside your `if statement` will be executed.

The example you provided will check both `if statements`, and execute the code within if your `statement` is true.

Answer (score 0):

So have you tried the following?

```
if (!empty($username)) {
    // Do something to username
}

// Code here will still execute
```

So here the if statement will run if it is true otherwise it will just skip it.

elseif will have to go after an if and catches a next scenario, but if they need to be run all then don't use elseif

```
if ($condition) {
    // code to run if statement passes
} elseif ($condition) {
    // only checks the condition if the first if is not run
} else {
    // has no condition but only runs if all above does fail to run
}
// Code here will still run as long as the above does not cancel the script. As Fatals, exit() die() return etc.
```

Comment: So I don't think the issue is in the if clause, it is more likely to be in the query to a database or similar. You probably need to append the changes to each other in the query used to update the data